# R - =if max statement from excel to R

Tags: r

Within a data frame. I want to compare today's value against a look back 'n' day period.

I know how to do it in excel for comparing today's value to see if it was higher than the previous 10 days.

```
=IF(A11>MAX(A1:A10),1,0)
```

How can I do the same logic within a function in R?

The output would look like this below:

```
  Column Output 
1   12    NA
2   13    NA
3   14    NA
4   15    NA
5   9     NA
6   9     NA
7   7     NA
8   8     NA
9   16    NA
10  17    NA
11  20    1
12  14    0
13  9     0
14  8     0
15  6     0
16  5     0
17  28    1
```

In row 11. Because value 20 is higher than the previous 10 days it denotes a 1 value.

In row 12, because value 14 is not the highest number in previous 10 days it receives a 0 value.

And it of course rolls on moving 10 day window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P Lapointe's answer is great but anytime I'm doing a 'rolling' calculation my first instinct is to think of `rollapply` from the zoo package.

```
is_last_greatest <- function(x){
    #' Given an input vector this returns
    #' 1 if the last element is greater than
    #' all of the other elements and 0 otherwise
    ifelse(all(tail(x,1) > head(x,-1)), 1, 0)
}

# We want to compare to the previous 10 values but the function
# I wrote requires us to include the value we're using as
# comparison so I set the width to 11
output <- rollapply(dat, 
          width = 11, 
          FUN = is_last_greatest, 
          fill = NA, 
          align = "right")

cbind(dat, output)
```

which gives

```
      dat vals
 [1,]  12   NA
 [2,]  13   NA
 [3,]  14   NA
 [4,]  15   NA
 [5,]   9   NA
 [6,]   9   NA
 [7,]   7   NA
 [8,]   8   NA
 [9,]  16   NA
[10,]  17   NA
[11,]  20    1
[12,]  14    0
[13,]   9    0
[14,]   8    0
[15,]   6    0
[16,]   5    0
[17,]  28    1
```

Comment: Ok great and if there were missing values in the data set then I could add this within roll apply? na.rm = TRUE or can we make it continue to roll if we have missing values....

Comment: It will do whatever the function you're calling specifies it to do.  So if you were doing a mean using rollapply you could pass along na.rm=TRUE if that's what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do that with `roll_maxr` from `RcppRoll`.

```
library(RcppRoll)
df$Output2 <- ifelse(df$Column>roll_maxr(lag(df$Column),11, na.rm = TRUE),1,0)

   Column Output Output2
1      12     NA      NA
2      13     NA      NA
3      14     NA      NA
4      15     NA      NA
5       9     NA      NA
6       9     NA      NA
7       7     NA      NA
8       8     NA      NA
9      16     NA      NA
10     17     NA      NA
11     20      1       1
12     14      0       0
13      9      0       0
14      8      0       0
15      6      0       0
16      5      0       0
17     28      1       1
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="  Column Output 
1   12    NA
                 2   13    NA
                 3   14    NA
                 4   15    NA
                 5   9     NA
                 6   9     NA
                 7   7     NA
                 8   8     NA
                 9   16    NA
                 10  17    NA
                 11  20    1
                 12  14    0
                 13  9     0
                 14  8     0
                 15  6     0
                 16  5     0
                 17  28    1",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @AndrewBannerman I saw your question in another answer about taking care of NAs. I added `, na.rm = TRUE` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method using `embed` to construct the comparison sets and performing the comparisons with `apply`.

```
# get a matrix for comparisons
myMat <- embed(df$Column, 11)
```

Here, this returns

```
myMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]   20   17   16    8    7    9    9   15   14    13    12
[2,]   14   20   17   16    8    7    9    9   15    14    13
[3,]    9   14   20   17   16    8    7    9    9    15    14
[4,]    8    9   14   20   17   16    8    7    9     9    15
[5,]    6    8    9   14   20   17   16    8    7     9     9
[6,]    5    6    8    9   14   20   17   16    8     7     9
[7,]   28    5    6    8    9   14   20   17   16     8     7
```

So the goal is to compare the value in the first column with those in the remaining column for each row.

```
as.integer(max.col(myMat) == 1L)
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Now, tack on the appropriate number of NA values, which is the number of columns in myMat minus one.

```
df$output2 <- c(rep(NA, ncol(myMat) - 1), as.integer(max.col(myMat) == 1L))
```

this returns

```
df
   Column Output output2
1      12     NA      NA
2      13     NA      NA
3      14     NA      NA
4      15     NA      NA
5       9     NA      NA
6       9     NA      NA
7       7     NA      NA
8       8     NA      NA
9      16     NA      NA
10     17     NA      NA
11     20      1       1
12     14      0       0
13      9      0       0
14      8      0       0
15      6      0       0
16      5      0       0
17     28      1       1
```

---

An advantage of `max.col` is that it is quite fast. One of its biggest drawbacks is that it does not have an na.rm argument to remove missing values. In the case that there are missing values, here is a method using `apply` on myMat instead of `max.col`.

```
apply(myMat, 1, function(x) as.integer(all(head(x, 1) > tail(x, -1))))
```

The operating comparison function here is

```
all(head(x, 1) > tail(x, -1))
```

Functions that produce the same result include the following

```
head(x, 1) == max(x) # or
x[1] == max(x)
```

and

```
1L == which.max(x)
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `embed` function. That looks like it could be useful. Thanks!